# Why flutter only showing WHITE SCREEN in release mode

Tags: flutter

I have no idea what's going on, No errors has been thrown in Debug Mode (it works and render fine) However, after running ***futter run --release*** the home screen is not showing only white screen

This is my main.dart file, I'm using GetX as route tool
**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Sample App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
      ),
      //defaultTransition: Transition.zoom,
      home: const Login(),
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: "/login", page: () => const Login()),
        GetPage(name: "/register", page: () => const Register()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is my login.dart
**login.dart**

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
          width: Get.width,
          margin: kDefaultBodyMargin,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Spacer(),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                child: TextField(),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                child: TextField(),
              ),
              const Spacer(flex: 5),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: Get.height * 0.05),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: Get.width,
                  height: 54,
                  child: TexButton(),
                )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

***pubspec.yaml***

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    
  badges: ^2.0.2
  circular_profile_avatar: ^2.0.5
  date_time_picker: "^2.1.0"
  dio: ^4.0.4
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+2
  get: ^4.6.1
  google_fonts: ^2.3.1
  extended_masked_text: ^2.3.1
  flutter_vector_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_phone_direct_caller: ^2.1.0
  jiffy: ^5.0.0
  loading_indicator: ^3.0.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

Comment: please provide screenshot

Comment: White screen only, What I am supposed to screenshot if there is nothing in release mode, this is terrible It should've thrown error in debug mode

Comment: tried `flutter run` with `--enable-software-rendering`?

Comment: No, I did not tried this, what does this thing do?

Comment: can you run it by flutter run -v --release and provide logs of it

Comment: after get white screen, check your log in debug console.It should throw some error

Answer (score 2):

because of the GetX package -> **GetMaritalApp** you used, I faced that problem today and tried all day long to solve it.

tried to downgrade the version of Get package put didn't work, so I simply get rid of it, not simply actually that took me time.

and BTW tried all solutions in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70558

Hope that helped, and Hope they will fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same white screen problem. This typically happens when you not use the getx in proper way in first screen. Use bindings and named transactions to go one screen to other. And do not inject dependency of first screen like Get.put(YourController()). Rather inject it in bindings. And extend the first screen view like YourView extends GetView.